# Python, Random number generation following Lomax distribution with outliers

Tags: python, numpy, statistics

I need to generate about 1000 integers within the range of 1000 following the Lomax distribution, but with outliers. See graph. How can I accomplish this in python? [image]

Comment: A conventional way to model outliers is that the observed data follow a mixture distribution, with one component being the "OK" data and one or more other components being the "outlier" data. For example, with 2 components, one OK and one outlier component, assume the mixing proportions are p and 1 - p. Toss a coin w/ probability p, if it comes up heads, then sample from the OK distribution. Otherwise, sample from the outlier distribution.

Comment: You need to provide more info as in how you would want your outliers look like (or what behavior you expect them to have). Otherwise you can generate the outliers in any way. Also, your image is not in "_range 1000_". Did you mean shape/scale of the distribution to be 1000?